# env variable is not working for Google Maps

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

I am creating a React App, with `create-react-app`, and trying to store some API keys in a `.env` file, but I have a problem when trying to access them.

This is the structure of the `.env` file:

```
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = apiKeyValue
```

As you can see the API key is for a Google Map, and here is my component that uses the Map:

```
export default function MapReturner() {

    const { isLoaded } = useLoadScript({
        googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY
    });

    if(!isLoaded) return <div>Loading...</div>

  return <Map />
};
```

But I get this error:

> Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys

and that's because when I try to `console.log()` the key, accessing it by `process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY` the browser's console returns `undefined`.

P.S: My `.env` file is outside the `src` folder, in the `root` directory, and I have `dotenv` installed.

Comment: Do you run `dotenv.config()`?

Comment: Please show the content of `package.json` and screenshot of your file structure

Answer (score 1):

make sure each variable has the REACT_APP prefix and the values don’t need to be wrapped inside quotations, **also make sure you run npm start after making changes to the .env**

also if you’re gonna use it in the backend you need to require dotenv and run. dotenv.config() like this:

```
require(“dotenv”).config();
```